# how to remove editing toolbar bottomsheet from html editor enhanced and add custom one

Tags: flutter-dependencies, pub.dev

reference image :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRxmm.jpg)

I used html editor enhanced's example from pub.dev

how to remove this X marked portion , even after removing all buttons or removing other options: doesnt resolve

I need to add custom editing bar at bottom of the sheet and also it should come above keyboard